# tmpfiles.d glob for directories only

Tags: systemd, wildcards

According to the documentation, I should be able to use globs to specify a path, however it seems that using `/*/` glob for directories isn't supported, is this because this type of glob is part of an "extended glob spec" that `tmpfiles.d` rules doesn't support?

Eg:

```bash
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ mkdir -p folder/{sub1,sub2}
$ touch folder/{file1,file2}
$ chmod -R 0700 folder 
$ echo "z $PWD/folder/*/ 0770 - - - -" | systemd-tmpfiles --create -
$ ls -l folder
total 8
-rwxrwx--- 1 mathiassven users    0 Nov 16 05:15 file1
-rwxrwx--- 1 mathiassven users    0 Nov 16 05:15 file2
drwxrwx--- 2 mathiassven users 4096 Nov 16 05:15 sub1
drwxrwx--- 2 mathiassven users 4096 Nov 16 05:15 sub2
```

As you can see, the rule applied to files as well.

As to why I would want to do this, I wanted to have a rule like this:

```
Z /srv/dav    0664 - - - -
Z /srv/dav/*/ 0774 - - - -
```

So that all files under `/srv/dav` have `0664`, but directories have `0774`. Although I am not sure whether I would be able to easily achieve that even if the globing for directories worked, since I don't know how `/srv/dav/*/` would interact with recursive applying it.

Comment: `tempfiles.d` is a directory, not a directory parser.  What shell (or other program) are you asking to expand your glob expression?

Comment: @SottoVoce what do you mean? I am talking about [tmpfiles.d rules](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/tmpfiles.d.html), in the docs itself it says "Lines of this type accept shell-style globs in place of normal path names"

Comment: The man page you cite is for a part of systemd, as the url and the pull-down in the top right corner indicate.  The page does say the syntax of some of the "types" accept "shell-style globs", but I don't find anything that indicates whether a shell is used to parse the globs or it's done by routines written into systemd or a library of systemd.  Or what "shell-type" means.  If it were a shell like Bash or Zsh, there could possibly be ways to enable advanced globbing syntax to select directories, as you asked for.  But it doesn't seem possible to know from the man pages.

Comment: @SottoVoce "shell-style globs" are systemd-implemented.  It does not invoke a shell to  to do it.  `systemd` documentation uses that terminology in a few places such as `systemctl` `systemd.list` and `systemd.unit`.